# Why does random not work in GUI in REBOL?

Tags: user-interface, random, rebol

This very simple script:

```
REBOL []
view layout [
    button "Rand" [alert to-string random 100]
]
```

gives the following results:

- 1-st run: 95, 52, 80, 96 ...
- 2-nd run: 95, 52, 80, 96 ...
- 3-rd run: 95, 52, 80, 96 ...

  ## ...

This is obviously not random because the same numbers repeat over and over again.

- Should I issue a bug report to the REBOL website?
- Is there a simple way to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you'd like to start with a different seed each time you run your script. Typically, the current time is used as a seed in these cases.
This has nothing to do with whether you're using the GUI or not.

Try:

```
REBOL []
random/seed now/precise
view layout [
    button "Rand" [alert to-string random 100]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you also restarting Rebol? Random gets seeded every first time, so it is not completely surprising to see the same sequence, in such a case.